# How to use AND/OR operators when building query in ax 2012 x++

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I couldn't really find anything about this, and i couldn't really figure it out.
Anyways, I have created a view which i need to filter using query/QueryRun etc. in x++.

The select statement for what i am trying to do looks like this

```
  while select salestable order by PtsWebDeliveryDate, salesId
    where 
(SalesTable.SalesStatus == SalesStatus::Delivered && !SalesTable.PtsProdNorwood && SalesTable.CustAccount != acc && SalesTable.InvoiceAccount != acc &&
           salestable.PtsWebDeliveryDate >= today() && salestable.PtsWebDeliveryDate <= today()+daysahead)
           ||
          (
            SalesTable.SalesStatus == SalesStatus::Backorder && SalesTable.SalesType == SalesType::Sales && !SalesTable.PtsProdNorwood &&
             SalesTable.CustAccount != acc && SalesTable.InvoiceAccount != acc &&
          (
                (salesTable.PtsSalesorderPacked  && salestable.PtsWebDeliveryDate >= today() && salestable.PtsWebDeliveryDate <= today()+daysAhead)
            ||
                (!salesTable.PtsSalesorderPacked && salestable.PtsWebDeliveryDate >= d && salestable.PtsWebDeliveryDate <= today()+daysahead))
          )
{
//Do stuff
}
```

As you can see i have som OR operators which i need to use. i have startet building the query in x++ and this is what i got:

```
q = new Query();
q.addDataSource(TableNum("packlistview"));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addSortField(fn[_OrderBy], _direction);

q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, SalesStatus)).value(queryValue(SalesStatus::Delivered));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsProdnorwood)).value(queryValue(NoYes::No));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, CustAccount)).value(queryValue(!acc));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsWebDeliveryDate)).value(queryrange(today(),today()+daysahead));

//OR
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, SalesStatus)).value(queryValue(SalesStatus::Backorder));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, SalesType)).value(queryValue(SalesType::Sales));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsProdnorwood)).value(queryValue(false));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, CustAccount)).value(queryValue(!acc));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, InvoiceAccount)).value(queryValue(!acc));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsSalesorderPacked)).value(queryValue(false));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsWebDeliveryDate)).value(queryrange(d, today()+daysahead));

//OR
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsSalesorderPacked)).value(queryValue(false));
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, PtsWebDeliveryDate)).value(queryrange(d, today()+daysahead));


    qr = new queryRun(q);

        while( qr.next())// && counter < 100
        {
             //Do stuff
        }
```

So how do I do incorporate the OR operators with this?

Cheers guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make a temporary table  out of it, doing all the filtering in a standard select statement, and later i used a x++ querybuilding to add sorting and the different stuff needed. this worked out great and felt more easy to do rather than injecting long string queries into the queryobjects.

But thanks for the answers :)

Comment: This sould work fine. However, don't be afraid of string queries, as the query framework runs it through the database as filtered-well-formed SQL strings. One or another will work fine with appropiate indexes as the final SQL query will be equally valid.

Answer (score 6):

You can generate the querystring with your criteria like this:

```
.value(strfmt("((Field1 == %1 && Field2 == %2) || Field1 != %3)", 
 var1, var2, var3, varX, ...));
```

May be it's not very smart but its the way the standard does. You can use `queryValue` function with some variables like base enums or dates to get the proper query string for each value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use comma separated values and pass the csv to the value function like this
q.dataSourceNo(1).addRange(fieldNum(PackListView, SalesStatus)).value(queryValue(SalesStatus::Delivered) + "," + "Open order"));

Comment: i have noticed i can do this by inserting fields into the range node of the view->metadata->datasource, but i kinda want it so that if the first block of filter-code doesn't return TRUE, then go for the next block of filter-code, since i have added the parentheses to each "block" of code so that all code wrapped in parentheses need to return true, if not, "check this other block of code". Will this help me achieve this? thanks for the answer, my friend.

Comment: There is another way to specify OR AND operators in query See this link http://www.axaptapedia.com/Expressions_in_query_ranges